# Newbie Getting error: expected ')' before ',' token

Tags: c

I am writing a program that calculates the square of two values (I must use a function.) I am sure that there are many mistakes but, I just can't seem to pick them out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

int integer1, integer2, total = 0;
int squared(int integer1, int integer2);
int main(void)
{
   printf("Enter two numbers to be Squared\n");
   scanf("%d%d",&integer1,&integer2);
   printf("Square of entered numbers = %d\n", squared(integer1,integer2));

   return 0;
}
int squared(int integer1, int integer2)
{
    int total;
    total = integer1 + integer2;
    return total *= total;
}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#define squared

int squared(int integer1, int integer2);

#endif
```

Comment: It looks like you're not clear on what `squared` is supposed to do. You declare the function with three arguments (and you haven't specified the types of the arguments), but you call it with just one argument. Decide exactly what `squared` is supposed to do; then you can implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you don't really need to specify the type `int` for the arguments that the function `squared` takes, because `int` is assumed whenever type is not specified, it is never bad to just put them down, as in:

```
int squared(int integer1, int integer2, int total);
// instead of
// int squared(integer1, integer2, total);
// both at the prototype and the definition of the function
```

Then again, you may just leave that out.

There are real problems in your function `squared`'s definition. You aren't using semicolons `;`, and you have written a return for the first statement, where I think you don't really want to return anything yet. You probably just wanted:

```
int squared(int integer1, int integer2, int total)
{
    total = integer1 + integer2;
    return total *= total;
}
```

One another important thing is, you are giving 2 less arguments to the `squared` function call from your `main` function. `squared` awaits for 3, you give it just 1. You probably wanted to call it as following:

```
...
    printf("Square of entered numbers = %d\n", squared(integer1, integer2, total));
...
```

Lastly, you shouldn't be using variables that you haven't given a value to. `integer1` *hopefully* will have a value assigned, `integer2` also, *hopefully*. But `total` won't be assigned a value by the time you call the `squared` from `main`. You can just initialize it with a `0` or something, like this:

```
...
    int integer1, integer2, total = 0;
...
```

Actually, you don't even need to have a `total` inside `main`, your `squared` function doesn't need a 3rd argument that holds `total`, as soon as you just declare an `int total` inside `squared`. But I won't get to that...

Answer (score 0):

The main issue throughout is that you don't specify the type of each function parameter. You need to tell the compiler that integer1 is an `int`, for example. Also, see haccks' answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two return statements one after the other are useless. The second return statement is unreachable. And you missed semicolons at the end of both the lines. May be this is the function you wanted:

```
int squared(int integer1,int integer2,int total)
{
   total = integer2+integer2;
   return total*total;
}
```

This calculates the sum of the two values and returns the square of the sum.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the function definition you need to change even the function call,

```
printf("Square of entered numbers = %d\n",squared(total));
```

to

```
printf("Square of entered numbers = %d\n",squared(integer1,integer2,total));
```

so that function call gets the value to add. read some basic c programs to know the format and syntax.

Answer (score 0):

With all above answers, you seem to have missed `;` in the return statement of your function.